# Trouble with SVN on second port

Tags: apache-2.2, svn

Got apache 2.2 listening on 2 ports: one for public serving and just added the second one for maintenance purposes.
Now,
Here's what works:

```
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName some.public.domain
    DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Location /svn>
                DAV svn
                SVNPath /var/svn
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

And this doesn't:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:40>
        ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www_tmp
        <Location /svn>
                DAV svn
                SVNPath /var/svn/concrete_repo
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Accessing http://localhost:40/svn results in a

```
File does not exist: /var/www_tmp/svn
```

record in apache error log.
Any ideas?

TIA.

Comment: Basic question: Does /var/www_tmp/svn exist?

Comment: Nope, neither does /var/www/svn from the first config (edited to make it clear). Mapping to a physical dir should be done by DAV module that refuses to work.

Comment: Ah, of course. Sorry I missed the DAV part, it's been a while since I set up subversion

Comment: you compare document root with svn added with document root only! 

The error is about /var/www_tmp not existsing, not /var/www_tmp/svn not existing.

DocuemtnRoot has to be a real physical directory, the "Location" stuff is a virtual path referring to the path that is requested by the browser when accessing this virtual host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's what has worked out:

```
<Location /svn>
        DAV svn
        SVNParentPath /var/svn
        SVNListParentPath on
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

Document root should exists, the Dav mapping is made only on the Location part.

In other words apache (without Dav) must be aware of its document root, then mod_dav can do the trick and create a "virtual" DOCUMENT_ROOT/svn

Comment: /var/www_tmp is an existing location

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this directive before the VirtualHost?

```
NameVirtualHost *
```

Comment: Listen 40
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
  DocumentRoot /var/www_tmp
```

and

```
  SVNPath /var/www/svn
```

probably a typo...fix it and see what happens

Comment: Edited the first post.